If a convex set E is contained in a unit ball B, with vol(E)/vol(B)>1-\varepsilon, can we find r close to 1 such that E contains B(0,r)?
Suppose that $E$ is a convex set and $B$ is the unit ball in $R^n$. Let $\varepsilon$>0 be a constant small enough. If we have $\frac{vol(E)}{vol(B)}>1-\varepsilon$, can we find $r>0$ close to 1 such that $B(0,r)\subset E$? I have tried to estimate that for each $x\in \partial B$, the distance between $x$ and $\partial E$ is small. But I can not estimate the distance between $x$ to $\partial B$ for each $x\in \partial E$. How can I estimate $r$?

You should include your work explicitely in your post

Look for counter-examples. And your question does not make sense sicne $\epsilon$ does not seem to play any role (can I take $\epsilon=2$?).
